# xPages extension library 9 designer client to 8.5.x server

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

My designer client is 9.0.1 but my development server (Non Local) is 8.5.3 FP3.  I only recently (for connect 2014) upgraded my client ot 9.0.1.  Was hoping to continue using it until we upgrade servers.

I have 2 questions.

1 - Can I build an xPage in my 9.0.1 client and open it up in a browser on my server without any issues (including adding in stuff from extension library that is in my designer client)?  I am not familiar with how to setup the extension library on the server so I can use it.

2 - I create an xPage, put in extension library name picker (Not sure where I found the example) and open it up via an @URLOpen() in my Notes Client.  It opens to the page correctly and it is viewable.  But when I click on the name picker I am getting the groups listing in my local names.nsf not the server names.nsf that the code is running on.  This test database resides on the 8.5.3 dev server mentioned above.  How do I get it to use server names.nsf on the client when I am clicking on a button?  (I need to be able to run it from client on the short term as well as browser)

Here is the code I am using:

```
 <xp:panel>
  <xp:panel>
    <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djName">
      <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookDb="ServerNameJBVDOMD01A!!names.nsf">
          </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
      </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:namePicker>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:djextNameTextBox id="djName" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true">
      </xe:djextNameTextBox>
  </xp:panel>
 </xp:panel>
```

Comment: From my experience, you can run an application created using a 9+ Designer client without problems on an 8.5.3 server. The only thing you need to be aware of is using functions that were introduced in 9+. The same applies to using controls from the Extension Library: anything introduced in 9+ will not work.

Answer (score 5):

1. In xsp.properties you can compile an application against a specific version - Minimum supported release.